# What is the difference between `/sbin/ip route` and `/sbin/route`?

Tags: networking, ip, route, iproute

Linux comes with two utilities

- `/sbin/route`
- `/sbin/ip route`

What is the difference between the two and what is the rule of thumb to use when you decide which one of the two you should use? I know they're both documented in two separate locations,

- `man 8 route`
- `man 8 ip-route`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`route` is the old traditional tool and available on numerous Unix systems. `ip` belongs to the iproute2 suite which is a Linux only tool and uses the Netlink API, which is a socket like interface for accessing kernel information about interfaces, address assignments and routes. It replaces most of the functionality of `ifconfig`, `route`, `netstat` and a few others.

I assume you're on Linux, then you should use `ip` since `route` and `ifconfig` are deprecated, although still widely used.

Further reading:

- [ifconfig vs iproute2](http://techblog.rosedu.org/ifconfig-vs-iproute.html)
- [iproute2: Life after ifconfig](http://andys.org.uk/bits/2010/02/24/iproute2-life-after-ifconfig/)
- [Deprecated Linux networking commands and their replacements](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/)

Comment: +1 for mentioning it is **Linux only**. On a site named *Unix & Linux* that is worth mentioning.

Comment: I always wondered why stick only to the non-portable Linux utilities, specially when they require you to be much more verbose. I find more comfortable to write `ifconfig eth0 up 192.168.0.1/24` than `ip link set dev eth0 up && ip addr change dev eth0 192.168.0.1/24`.

Comment: @ntrrgc You can shorten this to `ip l s eth0 up && ip a c dev eth0 192.168.0.1/24`. Furthermore the `/24` syntax is not implemented in all `ifconfig` versions, on some systems you have to write `netmask 255.255.255.0` which makes it rather verbose. But I agree `ifconfig` is often shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Different commands, different syntax.

`route` stems from very very long ago and still exists mostly because it has always existed and some stuff still expects it to be there.

`ip` belongs to the `iproute2` package and can do everything `route` and `ifconfig` can and much, much, MUCH more.

Full documentation on the `ip` command can be found [here](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2-toc.html) among other places.

TL;DR: Always use `ip`.